# Closing files with the Visual Studio Popup Navigator Window?

Tags: visual-studio

I'm looking for a quicker way to close files in visual studio so I can avoid X'ing out of a file, or hitting ctrl+f4. These are too slow for closing multiple files.

Is it possible to configure the popup navigator window (ctrl+tab) to close files somehow?
Like maybe clicking a file with the middle click on a mouse, or area dragging over a few files and hitting del?

I'd also welcome any other way of closing multiple files in a quick manner.

Comment: Middle-click in any location of the tab.

Comment: Pin files that you want to keep open and then close unpinned files. If you use vertical tabs, you can click x repeatedly without moving the mouse too. While not exactly the best option, it does works relatively well. Or close all files and reopen the one you need when needed.

Comment: I think Phil had the most useful answer, I'll have to make better usage of the pinning feature.

Answer (score 1):

Works for me by clicking the middle mouse button down anywhere on the tab towards the top of the window.

Perhaps you could remap the keyboard shortcut from 'ctrl + f4' to 'ctrl + w' to mimic typical behavior of other applications? Keyboard shortcuts can be accessed through:

*Tools>Options* - then look for *Keyboard* under the *Environment* tab. To access the shortcut for closing a tab, search for *Window.CloseDocumentWindow*

Hope that helps - I'm unaware of any means to close multiple windows at once.